# Dynamically set base in vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am trying to dynamically pass in data to set the base for vue-router. Is it possible to setup a separate function elsewhere that passes in a base name variable? For example, if an editor wanted to set the base name via a CMS, I’d want a way to pass (or import) that name through.

```
// router/index.js

export default new VueRouter({
base: '[PASS BASE NAME HERE]',
routes: [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/contact',
    name: 'Contact',
    component: Contact
  }
],
mode: 'history'
})
```

Comment: If the routes still use the same nested routes then couldn't you just use [dynamic route matching](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html) instead?

Comment: Do you want to change `base` from home or contact ?

Comment: @lamelemon - For example, with dynamic routing, would i be able to just set the base as `'/:brandname'` ? How would you go about setting specific 'brands' that can be accessed if its done dynamically? Let's say you want to have it only accessible for brands X, Y, Z. Is that defined somewhere? Thanks

Comment: @slipkid I was thinking something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6xu48og7/1/) and then importing your store or some shared state into the router file and using that shared state in a navigation guard to check against allowed brands.

Comment: @lamelemon thanks this is very helpful but may be too complicated for what i am requesting: I simply want to create a customizable `base` and have it configurable at runtime. So if a placeholder variable was defined on my `index.html`, I could pass that variable into the router as the name of the `base`.

Comment: @slipkid well i think your only other options are having a variable defined before you instantiate your router and use that variable as the base or [dynamically adding new routes](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-instance.html#methods) when you do have that variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up setting a variable on my `index.html` and importing it to the router. This can also be done by importing a variable from a module js file, but setting it on the `html` seems to avoid build issues. Simpler solution than I thought, thanks @lamelemon.

```
// index.html

    var serializedModel = @Html.Raw(Model.Serialized());


// router/index.js

    var baseUrl = serializedModel.BaseUrl;

    export default new VueRouter({
      base: baseUrl,
      mode: 'history',
      routes: [{...}]
    })
```